# get all words starting with @ character

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying out this regex to retrieve words out of a string that has a `@` at the beginning.

`'@yoMan is going crazy with @yoker-wiy'.match(/\b@\S+\b/g)`

It doesn't work. It only works with alphabets but not with characters like @ or #

Earlier I was trying `/@(\w+)/g` but it trims out `-wiy` from the word `yoker`. Sorry, not at all good with regex.

I think this question has  a duplicate that I'm not able to find. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It doesn't match the dash (`-`) because that isn't matched by `\w`. If you want to allow a dash as well, try `@([\w\-]+)`

Comment: Try `(?:\s|^)@(\S+)` https://regex101.com/r/6HPhQV/1

Comment: It should be `/\B@(\S+)\b/g`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's my Regex. thanks.

Comment: though @WiktorStribiżew solution doesn't match special characters all the way through to the end. Code Maniac's code works fine in this case.

Comment: As always, if you can describe the requirements in natural language, you can convert that to a regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Earlier I was trying /@(\w+)/g but it trims out -wiy from the word
>   yoker

Because \w includes `alphabets ( both case ), digits and _` not `-` so you get only utpo `@yorker`

---

Simply you can use `split`, `filter` and  `startsWith`

```js
let str = '@yoMan is going crazy with @yoker-wiy';
let final = str.split(/\s+/)
               .filter(v => v.startsWith('@'))
console.log(final)
```

---

With match you can use  `@[^\s]+`

```js
let str = '@yoMan is going crazy with @yoker-wiy';
let final = str.match(/@[^\s]+/g)
             
console.log(final)
```

Comment: wow it was that simple. I really need to put more effort into learning it. thanks.

Comment: @JayWadhwa Note it is not the same as `/\B@(\S+)\b/g`. Please  explain what you need to get from a `Hey,@my-best-friend!` string.

Comment: `/@[^\s]+/g` works for me. `/\B@(\S+)\b/g` doesn't match characters all the way through to the end.

Comment: @JayWadhwa  Then use `str.match(/@\S+/g)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const re = '@yoMan is going crazy with @yoker-wiy'.match(/(?:^|\W)@(\w+|^-)(?!\w)/g);
   console.log(re);
```

This is the regex that you are looking for.

Comment: thanks. but it still doesn't work. I get `yorker` not `yorker-wiy`

Comment: `/@[^\s]+/g`. Your code still doesn't work, make sure to test it out before updating. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the word-boundaries (`\b`) to a line-start (`^`) and line-end (`$`) and it will work.

```js
console.log(
  '@yoMan is going crazy with @yoker-wiy'
    .split(/\s+/g)
    .filter(s => s.match(/^@\S+$/g))
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: I like how I got immediately down-voted right as I got up-voted. Someone must be botting...